# how to write Unittets for a method which is returning a method

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
def acquisition_required(method):
    def wrapped_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result=some complex code
        if not result:
            some code is here
        else:
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
return wrapped_method
```

I would like to write a Unittest for this 
  eg.

`assertEqual, assertTrue..`
But i don't know how to test it i have done unittesting for function returning some values or True/False.
I don't want any code just concept

Comment: You do it the same way: you *call* the method returned by the decorator, and verify that it produces the expected values.

Comment: @tobias_k I did some correction now it is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to do this as below:

```
 with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self.assertRaises(your_module.acquisition_required(method))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function will be success then the return value will be the reference of getting method. It means you can use the assertEqual method of unittest module. Like below:

```
import unittest 
import your_module

class ConfigParserTestCases(unittest.TestCase):

def test_return_method(self):
    self.assertEqual(your_module.acquisition_required(method), method)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Note: If your implementation contains Exceptions (Eg.: try-except for error handling), you can test the Exception case with "assertRaises" method of unittest module. From the [Official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Eg. in your case (if you want to test ValueError exception):

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    self.assertRaises(your_module.acquisition_required(method))
```

Comment: Comparing two methods for equality just checks if they are the same object; not terribly useful.

Comment: I agree, but as I see this function is a decorator and the return value of it is the same object than input object in case of correct working. The exception or error handling etc... are different story as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I am getting issues like how to import method( parameter ) in unittest file